# Support of joint pdf being the Cartesian product of supports of the one-dimensional conditionals

Tags: probability

**Note: This is a homework problem so please DO NOT PROVIDE A COMPLETE SOLUTION. Some gentle hints would be good.**

Suppose $X_1,\, \ldots ,\, X_p$ have a $p$-variate joint pdf whose support is the Cartesian product of the supports of the one-dimensional conditionals, show that the joint pdf is uniquely determined from the one-dimensional conditionals.

**My Attempt**

Without loss of generality, let $p=2$ and call the two random elements $X$ and $Y$. Let $\text{supp}\, f_Y (y) = \{ y_0 \leq y \leq y_2\}$ and $\text{supp}\, f_{X\vert Y} (x) = \{ x_0 \leq x \leq x_2\}$ ($x_0,\, x_2$ may be dependent on $Y$). Then by assumption, $\text{supp}\, f_{X,\, Y} (x, y) = \{ (x,\,y): x_0 \leq x \leq x_2,\,y_0 \leq y \leq y_2 \}$.

For any $(x_1,\, y_1)\in \text{supp}\, f_{X,\, Y}(x,\, y)$,
\begin{align}
F_{X,\, Y} (x_1,\, y_1) &= \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \int_{y_0}^{y_1} f_{X,\,Y}(x,\, y) dy\, dx\\
&= \int_{y_0}^{y_1} \int_{x_0}^{x_1} f_{X\vert Y}(x)dx f_Y(y) dy.
\end{align} 
Now, $f_{X,\,Y}(x,\, y)$ is obtained by differentiating $F_{X,\,Y}(x,\, y)$ but from the above equality, we know that for any $(x_1,\, y_1)$ in the support of $f_{X,\,Y}(x,\, y)$, $F_{X,\,Y}(x_1,\, y_1)$ is uniquely determined by $f_{X\vert Y}(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. Therefore, $f_{X,\,Y}(x,\, y)$ is uniquely determined by the one-dimensional conditionals.

**My Question**

I don't feel like the above argument is enough because it seems too trivial to me. So I must have missed something? Could anyone tell me what that is please? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply, for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ to be non-zero, both multiplicands in its expansion must be non-zero, i.e. $f_Y(y)$ and $f_{X|Y}(x)$. So, why did you prefer using joint CDF?

Comment: @gunes I was trying to bring in the supports of the pdfs involved. But I guess you're right.

Comment: @gunes $f_{X,\, Y}(x,\, y) = f_{X\vert Y}(x) f_Y(y)$ alone does not guarantee that the joint is uniquely determined by the conditionals, right?

Comment: Having $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ (the marginals) doesn't determine the joint, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: In the title, by "one-dimensional conditionals" you must mean the $p$ *marginals,* right?  Otherwise you're asking about an uncountable Cartesian product, which makes little sense in this context.  By the way, the whole interest in this question lies in the case $p\gt 2:$ when $p=2$ it is indeed trivial.  You should therefore rethink the justification for your "wlg" assertion at the outset.

Comment: @gunes Yes I agree. But do things change when the support of the joint is the Cartesian product of those of the conditionals?

Comment: @whuber It was written as "one-dimensional conditionals" in the homework so I'm also confused. If it's indeed the marginals, could you give a hint on how to prove this for $p>2$? Thanks a million.

Comment: You appear to be asking two separate questions and they aren't really compatible.  If you're asking about the support, you're talking about the marginals.  If you're asking about the joint distribution, you must be talking about the conditionals.  Please decide which question you are asking and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @whuber could you please provide more details on why the problem must be about marginals when it is asking about support? Does it not make sense to talk about, for example, the support of $f_Y(y)$ and that of $f_{X\vert Y}(x)$? Thanks.